# Extract dates from R script

Tags: r, date, stringr

I have a long R script that I need to extract many dates from. I'm treating the script as a text file, and am trying to find the dates with regex look around functions.

Here is an example of a chunk of code containing dates:

```
Chamber1_3 <- subset(Chamber1Exp, Chamber1Exp$RealTime>=as.POSIXct("2019-05-21 06:01:45") & 
Chamber1Exp$RealTime<= as.POSIXct("2019-05-21 06:23:58"))

plot(Chamber1_3$RealTime[Chamber1_3$Status=="PRE"],Chamber1_3$N2O_ppm[Chamber1_3$Status=="PRE"],
xlim=as.POSIXct(c("2019-05-21 06:01:45", "2019-05-21 06:23:58")), 
ylim=c(.34,.35))
```

I want to recover "2019-05-21 06:01:45" and ""2019-05-21 06:23:58". They are repeated twice in the code, I just want them once.

I'm testing RegEx snippets in the RegExplain add-in to RStudio. I was trying to use a look-around function to capture the dates following the common text `'as.POSIXct('`

I thought this should work but I get nothing.

```
(?<=Xct\(\")(?=\")
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract all the 4 numbers- 2 numbers- 2 numbers one or more spaces 2 numbers:2 numbers: 2numbers, then unlist and take only the unique values.

```
your_vec <- c('Chamber1_3 <- subset(Chamber1Exp, Chamber1Exp$RealTime>=as.POSIXct("2019-05-21 06:01:45") & 
Chamber1Exp$RealTime<= as.POSIXct("2019-05-21 06:23:58"))

plot(Chamber1_3$RealTime[Chamber1_3$Status=="PRE"],Chamber1_3$N2O_ppm[Chamber1_3$Status=="PRE"],
xlim=as.POSIXct(c("2019-05-21 06:01:45", "2019-05-21 06:23:58")), 
ylim=c(.34,.35))')

unique(unlist(str_extract_all(your_vec, '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\\s+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}')))

leaving:
[1] "2019-05-21 06:01:45"
[2] "2019-05-21 06:23:58"
```

Comment: Thanks!! Not sure why my code didn't work but I am happy to stop beating my head against that wall. I bet I'll riff off this example a lot in the future.

Comment: One thing would be that you'll need to double backslash your regex patterns in R! As per the rest of the pattern, it's not quite clear what your syntax ought to be doing. In any case, extracting the exact pattern of dates is a more general solution than relying on POSIXct  - especially as seen here: as.POSIXct(c("2019-05-21 06:01:45"...) where you'd need to take care of the c() function too